# Problem Delphi vcl setstyle Error Access violation at adress 0063E1D9 in

Tags: delphi, themes, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

### I am programming Delphi 10.1. Error TrySetStyle

```
Uses vcl.themes;

procedure TForm1.IcebergClassico1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Iceberg Classico');
end;

procedure TForm1.LavenderClassico1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Lavender Classico');
end;

procedure TForm1.Light1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Light');
end;

procedure TForm1.Luna1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Luna');
end;
```

---

Error:
[Access violation at adress 0063E1D9 in *.exe. Read of address 00000000.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpBel.png)

---

Project->Options->Application
Enable Runtime Themes checked
Enable High-DPI checked
Project->Options->Application->Appearance

### themes checked

Didn't help `TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Luna',false);`

Comment: Are these styles included in your app? Does this happen in an empty app with just that code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, tested with Delphi 10.1 on Windows 7. Trace into the code, to find the exact line that triggers the error.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it in the following way:

```
   { Private declarations }
  public
      Tema: TIniFile;
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  frmTemas: TfrmTemas;
implementation

    enter code here

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmTemas.btnStyleClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Tema.WriteString('style','value',cbListStyles.Text);  /// Write selected value into cmbb of the session.
   TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(Tema.ReadString('style','value','Windows'));  // Read last theme and apply value from session
end;

procedure TfrmTemas.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var
  estilo: string;
begin
   for  estilo in  TStyleManager.StyleNames  do
        cbListStyles.Items.Add(estilo);    // Add all styles to ComboBox
   Tema:= TIniFile.Create(GetCurrentDir+'\tools.ini');  // Create archive .ini
   TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(Tema.ReadString('style','value','Windows'));  // Read last theme and apply value from session
end;
end;
```

I hope it helps.